# CMake: Cannot find library without absolute path

Tags: linux, build, cmake

This work fine.

```
add_executable( my_exe file.c )
target_link_libraries( my_exe /lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 )
```

But why doesn't this work?

```
link_directories( /lib64 )
add_executable( my_exe file.c )
target_link_libraries(my_exe ldap_r-2.4 )
```

Error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lldap_r-2.4
```

Directory /lib64 contains the following files:

```
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 -> libldap_r-2.4.so.2.5.6
libldap_r-2.4.so.2.5.6
```

Answer (score 2):

When you're trying to link using the name `ldap_r-2.4`, the linker will search for files with `lib` prepended to it, and default suffixes appended, like `.a`, `.so`, so it would work if you had a file with the name `libldap_r-2.4.so` (which could be a symlink for the file with the version number) in one of the link directories used (`/lib64` is most likely included in the default search paths on your system, so it shouldn't be necessary to manually add it).

For me, on ubuntu 14.10 there is only a symlink called `libldap_r.so`, pointing to `libldap_r-2.4.so.2.8.3`, so the correct way to link with this library would be:

```
target_link_libraries(my_exe ldap_r)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! There is a libldap_r.so but it is pointing to libldap_r-2.3.so.0.2.15 which is not the version that I want.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use [FIND_LIBRARY](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html) than linking manually.

If your library is installed as default you don't have to include the version.

```
target_link_libraries(my_exe ldap_r)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. find_library( LDAP_LIB NAMES ldap_r HINTS /lib64 ) and message( "LDAP LIBRARY ${LDAP_LIB}" ) results in the following output LDAP LIBRARY LDAP_LIB-NOTFOUND. /lib64 contains libldap_r-2.4.so.2 and libldap_r-2.4.so.2.5.6

Answer (score 0):

The /lib64 folder is probably not in your linker search paths. 
Try exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include this as follows. This must be done in the same shell that you are about to invoke cmake from.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib64/
```

Also, this does not work:

```
target_link_libraries(my_exe ldap_r-2.4 )
```

because that makes CMake look for libldap_r-2.4.so which is NOT in your /lib64 directory. If you don't mind creating a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.5.6 /lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so
```

However, as Cristian Bidea said, it is better use the FIND_LIBRARY utility.

Comment: If I echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH it shows ":/usr/local/lib" and I link towards other libraries that are not located in "/usr/local/lib". I tried adding /lib64 to LD_LIBRARY_PATH but FIND_LIBRARY still can't find the library. @balajeerc